# Using fplot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I am trying to plot a function and its derivative using `fplot`.

```
fplot('3*x*sin(x) - 2*x', [-2*pi 2*pi], 'r')
```

This is working, But the command below is showing error.

```
fplot('diff(3*x*sin(x) - 2*x)', [-2*pi 2*pi], 'g')
```

Error Shown

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> fplot at 105
x = xmin+minstep; y(2,:) = feval(fun,x,args{4:end});
```

Please give me some suggestions?

Comment: What error is it showing ?

Comment: Try plotting the second plot in a new plot to see if it works.

Comment: @Pavan Ok, But what is the reason for that error.  `d = diff(3*x*sin(x)-2*x)` gives the derivative of that function. `fplot('d', [-2*pi 2*pi], 'g')` gives a wrong plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first calculate derivative, transform result in a string, and then plot obtained function:

```
syms x;
di = char( diff(3*x*sin(x)-2*x) );
fplot(di, [-2*pi 2*pi], 'g');
```

**Edit:** @shoelzer provides correct explanation for the error you've received.

Comment: `@zplesivcak`, Thank you for your fast reply

Answer (score 4):

The problem is including `diff` in the function string. Your function needs to produce N outputs for N inputs, but having `diff` give N-1 outputs. From the documentation on `fplot` (emphasis added):

> The function must be of the form y = f(x), where x is a vector whose range specifies the limits, and **y is a vector the same size as x** and contains the function's value at the points in x (see the first example).

[zplesivcak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365433/1339280) shows one way to work around this limitation. You could also evaluate the function non-symbolically:

```
x = linspace(-2*pi, 2*pi, 1000);
y = diff(3*x.*sin(x) - 2*x);
figure
plot(y)
```

Comment: `@shoelzer ` Thanks, But I was exploring the ``fplot` function.